# Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

How do I get or pass in the flow xml the value from a selectoneMenu field in an XHTML page.

Comment: change the title of the question so that it reflects the real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you've said, but you can do this at your xhmtl:

```
<selectOneMenu value="#{flowScope.value}">
...
</selectOneMenu>
```

This will store the value of your selectOneMenu into your flowScope. You can also try other scopes, according to what you want (viewScope, flashScope, etc ... - take a look at SWF documentation).

Answer (score 0):

How do I get or pass in the flow xml the value from a selectoneMenu field in an XHTML page.

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
   <h:outputLabel
  id="memberListLabel" value="MemberList}"
  for="memberList" styleClass="outputLabel" />
</td>
<td>
  <p:selectOneMenu id="memberList"
  value="#{memberForm.member}"
  tabindex="1"
  style="font-size:11px;float:left;width:159px;" >
<f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="---Select---" />
<f:selectItems value="#{memberList}" itemLabel="--Select--" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

your action will take care,save the data in flowScope not in xhtml page
```